# how to send input type button to php file with post

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I was working on a project and wanted to send the information over to another file to see if the button was clicked or not. I have more buttons that are the same with only different names and values so that's why I can't use submit on all the buttons.

```
 <form action="file.php" method = "post" >
       <input "type= "button" name = "normal" value = "normal">
<input "type= "button" name = "regular" value = regular">
<input  name = "submit" type = "submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
```

I have tried to send the information to file.php with session and just regular post but nothing seems to work. I only get errors that say undefined array key. here's what I tried

```
$_SESSION['normal'] = $_POST['normal'];
$normal = $_POST["normal"];
```

Comment: Why don't you use checkboxes?

Comment: If you really have to use a button, add a hidden input, and use JavaScript to fill in the value of the hidden input when the button is clicked.

Comment: You either have multiple submit buttons with names & values (easy to do)
OR
Use JS to to fill out a hidden input as @Barmar mentioned.

Comment: Only the submit button gets sent to the server automatically.

Comment: @barmar how do you use js to fill in the value of hidden input?

Comment: `document.getElementById("id-of-hidden-input").value = button.value;`